# How to scale SVG text clickable area?

Tags: svg, text

```
> <text x="0" y="50" font-family="Verdana" font-size="35" fill="blue"
> opacity="0">&#8203;Hello <animate attributeName="opacity"
> begin="theSVG.click" dur="3s" values="0;1;0" repeatCount="1"
> fill="freeze"> </animate>  </text>
```

As I learn SVG text, I am confused about how to scale the area where it is clickable to active the animate, since I found that I can only click "Hello" to active the animate, and other area is not clickable.
I have tried like padding-top/bottom, pointer-event, and the only way is to add " " in the text to enlarge the clickable area, do you guys have better ideas?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: you can't use `padding` in SVG. Also as I've explained in my answer to one of your previous questions you can use `begin="theSVG.click"`. This means that the svg element has `id="theSVG"`. This is alowing you to activate the animation by clicking the svg element. Add a border to the svg element to see where you can click.

Comment: If you need to scale the svg element consider using a viewBox attribute

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirement, and ended up by adding a separate *transparent* text element just before and just after the required one. The same click event was allocated to these transparent elements.
This doesn't increase the height of the clickable area, but does solve the particular problem where the text is just the single letter 'I' which has little area to click on